# Overriding Angulars ngShow and ngHide for some tags

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm currently working with Bootstrap and AngularJS and try to wrap some Bootstrap-components with Angular. I wrote a directive for opening and closing a collapse. 
It works fine if I name the directive just somehow, but it would be geat if I could extend ngShow and ngHide.

Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('collapse', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        priority: 99,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // Watch ng-show attribute and perform the correct actions
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function(value){
                if(value == true) {
                    $(element).collapse('show');
                } else {
                    $(element).collapse('hide');
                }
            });

            // Same for ng-hide
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngHide, function(value){
                if(value == false) {
                    $(element).collapse('show');
                } else {
                    $(element).collapse('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I know that I can completely remove ngShow's behaviour, but I want to remove the default behaviour just for Tags with the .collapse-Class.

```
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('ngShowDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        $delegate.shift();
        return $delegate;
    }]);
});
```

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: you are reimplementing http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: the only one thing you need it's write css for your '.collapse' class. Don't touch ng-show and ng-hide, work with css only =)

Comment: will try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/angularjs_de/6VErN/